# Add “Go get it” button for “Archaeologist” badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, edit-badges

Currently the “Archaeologist” badge doesn’t contain a “Go get it” button:

> [image: arch]

I suggest to add it with the link to the following search request:

> [lastactive:..6m](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A..6m)

Because it actually reflects the full set of posts that you can edit to make a progress to earning the badge.

Answer (score 8):

While this could be a good idea (just to be consistent), I don't think this was really meant to be a badge to "Go get it". This badge is more meant to be an encouragement to think about editing when you are browsing old posts. At least, that is how I made progress towards this badge: I read a lot of old posts, and if I see something I can improve, then I do so.

It is generally not a good idea to randomly start editing old posts, since this floods the "last active" page. While one or two edits are not a problem, more than that push fresh questions off the list, which is a problem, especially on small (beta) sites.

Comment: and personally flooded front pages make me irate, cause that's how I use my primary sites ._.

Comment: That last argument doesn't really hold up here. The Copy Editor badge would encourage that just as much while sending users on a journey to edit *any 500* posts. Older than 6 months or not, it would still flood the page.

Comment: @animuson But that is not a problem if the posts are, say, 1 hour old, and they still need an answer. (Or maybe 10 minutes old on SO)